# Is "screen_view" firebase event for iOS only?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I can see the `screen_view` events in the Firebase Console for my iOS app, but not for Android.

I have followed the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) to `setScreenName` but all I got are `user_engagement`.

Have anyone succeeded to get the `screen_view` events for Android app?

Comment: The `screen_view` event should work on Android too. If it doesn't for you, show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen
I have created a new Activity and call this code below on onCreate function
`mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(MainActivity.this, "Home Screen", "Class1");`

Then I check on firebase console the result event is "user_engagement" 
FIY : My device model is Mi A1 "7.1.2", and "firebase-core:10.0.1"

Comment: I know why that not show on my app 
This event has added on release "11.0.0" June 7, 2017